# How to adjust the height of 2 ChartAreas and Series names?

Tags: c#, charts

I'm struggling a bit to adjust the height of the two charts and the series names.

I tried with `Position.Height`, `Position.Y`, but no luck so far :/

[image]

chart1 size: 1900; 1029...

I want the ChartArea 0 to have 1420 height and ChartArea 1 460 height with the full 1029 length and not 50 / 50..
And a small white space in the middle of the both ChartAreas with 10 pixels so not to have a big space in the middle of the screen..

And: On the right side, X0 - X4 are Series2, how can I move to the chartarea1 with a Series2 title?

thanks <3

@TaW
Thanks for your input, i solved it with this:

```
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Position.Width = 85;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Position.Height = 70;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].Position.Width = 85;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].Position.Height = 30;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].Position.Y = 70;
```

Comment: This is possible but takes some experimentation.. - ou will need to control the size and location by setting the Position property, which contains both. And it is not in pixels but on % of the next outer container..

Comment: @TaW I got it, thank you ! :) Edited the working solution in the post